# What is "gonna transfer in" means?

Tags: formality

In my try to mix up English learning with web surfing I have been sticking on Reddit sometimes. Mostly my problems are in informal language which used in memes or comic strips. So, there is the instance:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kMm7.jpg

I can get it, but not really clear. I think it's because of last sentence. What is "gonna transfer some bullies in" means? That's funny if he wondering have more bullies in the school. But this "gonna" destroying my theory. Did he had intention make some bullies more angry?

Thank you!

ps: it would be great if you point grammar mistakes in this question.

Comment: It simply means that there was clearly a shortage of bullies in his school if he wasn't bullied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"transfer in" is a way that American schools describe students that a assigned to a particular school for administrative reasons.

The joke is that there's a person who is so comfortable being "dorky" that they're "going to transfer in" extra Bullies to create balance.

Answer (score 0):

In an educational context, to *transfer* is to proceed from attending one educational institution to attending another, without coming in at the very beginning of the program at the second. One is said to *transfer in* to the second or receiving institution, or to *transfer out* of the sending institution. This is usually intransitive, as something the student opts to do, but in the cartoon it is being used transitively: the official plans to arrange for some bullies to transfer in.